# i want to make app that use pexels api and i cant set the api in a request header

Tags: java, api, android-studio

I want to make app that use pexels api and I can't set the api in a request header
i work with java
can you help me

Comment: Header of what? You haven't shown any code for an API request

Comment: You can see  code here that adds the header you want https://github.com/medyas/WallBay/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ml/medyas/wallbay/network/pexels/PexelsCalls.java#L34-L38

Answer (score 0):

For setup the header authorization you need to put in your services declaration something like this:

```
@Headers("Authorization: " + ApiKey.PEXELS_TOKEN)
@GET("search")
fun getSearch(@Query("query") query: String?, @Query("per_page") itemNum: Int, @Query("page") numPage: Int): Call<List<¨Photo>>
```